# emailjs is not working. When I click the send button, nothing happens and no email is sent to me

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to set up emailjs, but for some reason, it won't work. When I click the send button, nothing happens. Can someone take a look at my code and see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

here's my form:

```html
 <section class="form">
            <form id="myform">
                <div class="wrapperform">
       
                    <label for="first"><input id="first" name="first" type="text" placeholder=" First Name"></label>
                    <label for="last"><input id="last" name="last" type="text" placeholder=" Last Name"></label>
                    <label for="emails"><input id="emails" name="emails" type="email" placeholder=" Email"></label>
                    <label for="phone"><input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder=" Phone Number"></label>
                    <label class="textarea" for="bigtext"><textarea name="message" id="message" style="width:100%; height:100%;" placeholder=" Message"></textarea></label>
                    <button class="submit" id="submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </section>
```

here is my JavaScript:

```
function sendMail(){
    let parms = {
        name: document.getElementById("first").value,
        last: document.getElementById("last").value,
        email: document.getElementById("emails").value,
        phone: document.getElementById("phone").value,
        message: document.getElementById("message").value,

    }

    emailjs.send("service_72h41ds","template_aoove3j",parms).then(alert("Email Sent!!")); 
}

const form = document.getElementById("myform");
form.addEventListener("submit", sendMail);
```

Not too sure what do

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` in your sendMail function

Comment: The thing inside `.then(...)` has to be a function.

Comment: PSA: It's 2024 and you can `await` in an `async` function to avoid the `.then()` madness.

Comment: The callback in `then` *should be* a function if it was to do anything useful, as-is it will do the alert immediately (making OP think it's been sent) - it's currently the equivalent of `let x = alert("sent"); ... .then(x)`

Comment: Thanks @Chris G. As soo as I added the event.preventDefault();, everything works.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that your button is of `type="submit"` - so when you click the submit button, your event fires, but then *immediately* submits the form, so your email does not get a chance to send.

Add

```
event.preventDefault();
```

in the submit handler.

*or*

Change button type to `type='button'` and change to a `click` handler on the button.